# Why is MSTest.exe not installed?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, tfs, mstest

I have a dev machine and a build machine, both of which have Visual Studio 2012 Premium Update 3 installed (Version 11.0.60610.01). Both machines are 64 bit and are running Windows Server 2012 Version 6.2 (Build 9200)

The Dev machine has the following folder which contains MSTest.exe

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE
```

On the build machine, that folder doesn't exist and searching for mstest.exe shows that it isn't on the build server anywhere.

Opening Control Panel > Programs and trying the Change operation doesn't provide any option to install mstest. All options shown in that Change window are identical on each machine.

The build server is also installed as a TFS agent

I've tried re-installing VS but no change.

Why isn't MStest.exe installed on the build machine and how can I get it installed?

Comment: What happens when you try to open a solution and run some unit tests from the build machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved - the test components were on the F drive for some reason

Answer (score 3):

I am using VS2017 and I was facing the same issue and I found it in here.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE

Anybody using the VS2017 and facing the same issue can search the directory I have mentioned above to search `MSTest.exe`

Comment: In my case, I found MSTest.exe at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE`. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional edition.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you did what I did.

If you install the update "2012.3" it will only install minimal components and not the full IDE. Try installing Visual Studio from the ISO (~2GB) and then apply the Update...

Comment: I do have the full Visual Studio IDE installed as well

Answer (score 0):

I found on a different directory:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe

EDIT: I came upon this page because I am trying to make the transition from Visual Studio to the Jetbrains Rider IDE and they assisted with some other questions on where to find dependencies for their command line Justmock runner [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/cannot-mock-the-profiler-must-be-enabled-to-mock-arrange-or-execute-the-specified-target)